# How to get the full pointer data in Parse.com

Tags: json, parse-platform

i'm making a new application using Parse.com as a backend, i'm trying to make less requests to the Parse, I have a class which is pointing to another object of another class.

```
Class1(things):

ObjectID       Name       Category(pointer)
JDFHSJFxv      Apple       QSGKqf343


Class2(Categories):

ObjectID    Name    Number    Image
QSGKqf343   Fruits  45        http://myserver.com/fruits.jpeg
```

when i'm trying to retreive data for my first class things using REST API i'm getting this json object :

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "Name": "Apple",
      "createdAt": "2015-07-12T02:50:20.291Z",
      "objectId": "JDFHSJFxv",
      "category": {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Teams",
        "objectId": "QSGKqf343"
      },
      "updatedAt": "2015-07-12T02:55:33.696Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

the json doesn't contains all the data included in the object i'm pointing to, I will have to make another request to get all the data of that object,

is There any way to fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Parse to return the related object in your query, via the `include` key.

e.g., add the following to your CURL `--data-urlencode 'include=category'`

Comment: save my day, thanks